# React Native, how to increase array index by using state?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a deck of cards and one card image is showed on the screen. When I press the card, I would like to update the array index to show the next card image on the array. For clarity, every card value is a string corresponding to its image. My code:

```
const deck1 = new cardDeck();
deck1.reset();

export default class Game extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {card: deck1.deck[0]};
}

get cardImage() {
switch (this.state.card) {
  case "AH":
    return require('../assets/images/PNG/AH.png');
  case "2H":
    return require('../assets/images/PNG/2H.png');
   .
   .
   .
  default:
    return require('../assets/images/PNG/AS.png');
 }
 }

handleOnPress = () => {
this.setState(prevState => {
  return {something here to increase the index}
}
)
}

render() {


return(
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleOnPress} >
  <Text> 

  <Image style={styles.img} source={this.cardImage} />

  </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 )
 }
 }
```

Comment: This means when user clicks on deck you need to push value somewhere else and cut one value from deck cards am I right????

Comment: @Amit Shakya When clicked, the index should increase by 1 and then the game shows another card image corresponding to the value of the next card item on the array. So the state deck1.deck[0] updates to deck1.deck[1]

Answer (score 0):

Okey I happened to figure it out. I edited the props and switch case to this:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {card: 0};
}

get cardImage() {
switch (deck1.deck[this.state.card]) {
case "AH":
return require('../assets/images/PNG/AH.png');
case "2H":
return require('../assets/images/PNG/2H.png');
.
.
.
default:
return require('../assets/images/PNG/AS.png');
}
}
```